# Multiple tag inputs with expansion panel in React with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, frontend, material-ui

I have multiple expansion panels and i am trying to add tags in each panel but, when i add a tag in a specific panel it automatically displays the tag for all the expansion panels.
I am using Material UI and React.

Please find the code attached below:

```
handleAddition(tag) {

    this.setState(state => ({ tags: [...state.tags, tag] }));
}
```

my constructor code:

```
 this.state = {
        students: [],
        searchedName: "",
        filteredStudents: [],
        tags: [],
    };

    this.filterList = this.filterList.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleAddition = this.handleAddition.bind(this);
```

Comment: Can you add the code for expansion panel as well ?

Comment: hope your trying to add a single tag to state, which will render in an expansion panel, but your state contains like if state.tags are, tags = [1,2,3],then arg tag is ex tag = 4, so   [...tags, tag] will contains all the tags [1, 2, 3, 4], Can you explain a bit please to help you out ?